# Crawler returns empty results

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I have constructed (with the help from stackoverflow) crawler for [this page](http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69), but results are blank. While single page spider works and scrapes all required items, crawler for the next pages doesn't. I don't understand what could the problem here.

Here is the crawler:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import re
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from urlparse import urljoin


from mymobile.items import MymobileItem


class MmobySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mmoby2" 
    allowed_domains = "http://mymobile.ge"
    start_urls = [
        "http://mymobile.ge/new/v2.php?cat=69"
    ]

    rule = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=\d*", ))
        , callback="parse_items", follow=True),)

    def parse_items(self, response):
        sel = Selector(response)
        titles = sel.xpath('//table[@width="1000"]//td/table[@class="probg"]')
        items = []
        for t in titles:
            url = sel.xpath('tr//a/@href').extract()
            item = MymobileItem()
            item["brand"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('^([\w\-]+)')
            item["model"] = t.xpath('tr[2]/td/text()').re('\s+(.*)$')
            item["price"] = t.xpath('tr[3]/td//text()').re('^([0-9\.]+)')
            item["url"] = urljoin("http://mymobile.ge/new", url[0])

            items.append(item)

        return(items)
```

Comment: You're missing `parse_start_urls` for getting the links for each item, which you'll pass via callback to `parse_items`.

Comment: I would try `SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("new/v2.php\?cat=69&pnum=\d*", ))` (notice the escaping of `?` to match a literal "?", not `php?` ("ph" and optional "p")

Comment: @paultrmbrth just escaped ? but it didn't help.

Comment: @Nanashi single page spider works perfectly without it. here is it: 
http://pastebin.com/RvdmtTyw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two major problems:

- the property is called [`rules`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.contrib.spiders.CrawlSpider.rules), not `rule`:

  ```
  rules = (Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("new/v2.php?cat=69&pnum=\d*", )), 
                callback="parse_items", 
                follow=True), )
  ```
- [`allowed_domains`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spider.Spider.allowed_domains) should be a list:

  ```
  allowed_domains = ["mymobile.ge"]
  ```

Also, you need to tweak the regular expression as Paul suggested in comments.

Comment: Thank you!

It worked. Strange part (for me, as a beginner) was that it started working not only after adding your suggestions, also removing the http:// from the allowed domains :).